# HTML5 "required" attribute on asp:DropDownList

Tags: asp.net, regex, html

Let's say I have this DDL on my page:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="senha" runat="server" required="required" CssClass="form-control">
    <asp:ListItem Value="" Text="empty" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="test1"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="2" Text="test2"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

In this one, the required field will work without problem, if you don't select a value, then it will block the submit.
But what if the initial value is 0?

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="senha" runat="server" required="required" CssClass="form-control">
    <asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="empty" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="test1"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="2" Text="test2"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Now the "required" attribute doesn't work anymore.
What I want to do is put a pattern in the value to only accept values greater than zero, but I'm not familiar with RegExp, and I don't know if the HTML "pattern" attribute will do what I want.
Can someone enlighten me?
I would rather use a solution that uses pure HTML, but if a minimal programming is required, then I don't have choice...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to write mark up the [RequiredFieldValidator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.requiredfieldvalidator(v=vs.110).aspx) should work

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="senha" runat="server" required="required" CssClass="form-control">
    <asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="empty" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="test1"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="2" Text="test2"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="reqSenha" runat="server" SetFocusOnError="true"  InitialValue="0" ErrorMessage="*" ControlToValidate="senha" />
```

Comment: Can this display a popup with the error message, like the HTML5 "required" attribute do?

Comment: You can set a message in the `ErrorMessage` attribute, where you put  the `RequiredFieldValidator` the message is going to be displayed, not as a popup, just as text, but it can be styled as one with `CSS`, use the `CssClass` attribute for this